# How to join same lines in textbox and count them

Tags: c#, winforms

Hey Guys I have Problem I have a textbox who will have sometimes same lines now I need to count them and show the number in joined line with the text

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] same =textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct().ToArray();
        textBox1.Text = string.Join("\r\n", same);
    }
```

in this code it will join the lines and I am able to see just one line but I need a count of lines and if I have some number in that line to count that also

for example:

1. Earth 2
2. Water
3. Air
4. Earth

Expected :

1. Earth    x2    4
2. Water
3. Air

Comment: `Earth x2 4`?? I don't get the idea..  Plz give us a clear example with more details

Comment: if i click the button twice to  count the lines and show the count in the same line and if i have number to add them

Comment: ofc if line is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, BTW I solve it this way.
First I made a class for each result item

### Result Class

```
public class Result
{
    public string Item{ get; set;  } 
    public int Count{ get; set;  }
    public int Value{ get; set;  } 
}
```

Then I have a button to translate the 'user input' to the desired format
You can run this method as textbox1_changed

### Button Translate Clicked Method

```
    private void btnTranslate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = textBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
        var results = new List<Result>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var text = item;
            var value = 0;
            var row = item.Split(' ').ToList();

            if (row.Count == 2) // item contains value like: Earth 2
            {
                text = row[0];
                Int32.TryParse(row[1], out value);
            }

            var result = results.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Item.Equals(text));
            if (result == null) // first time item apears in the list
            {
                result = new Result
                {
                    Item = text,
                    Count = 1,
                    Value = value
                };

                results.Add(result);
            }
            else // item added before should increase the count
            {
                result.Count++;
                result.Value += value;
            }
        }

        textBox2.Text = Prettify(results); // lets make the result pretty

    }
```

In the end I declared Prettify function to make the result as you wanted

### Prettify Method

```
    public string Prettify(List<Result> results)
    {
        var prettify = "";
        int row = 0;
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            prettify += $"{++row}. {result.Item}"; // 1. Earth

            if (result.Count > 1)
                prettify += $" x{result.Count}";   // 1. Earth x2
            if (result.Value > 0)
                prettify += $" {result.Value}";    // 1. Earth x2 4

            prettify += Environment.NewLine;

        }

        return prettify;
    }
```

Here is the output

## Output

[image: screenshot]

I guess the core is right, you could customize it
Have fun

Comment: Wow Thank you so much

Comment: While I have you do you want me to open new question or I can ask you here  for example if I have two words in the line like blue sky 2 it is not adding it is counting the lines but not adding the numbers and second I tried this code with Decimals and it is not working like Blue Sky100,35 can you help me with that? and I tried declaring the Count and Value as decimal

Comment: great news, it's so simple. if you wanna support floating numbers first change the `value` type from `int` to `double` all over the source, then replace tryParse with `double.TryParse(row[1], out value);` 
AND if you wanna support `sky blue`  change the `if` statement to `if (row.Count >1 )`   and some little changes in that if block

Comment: `if (row.Count > 1)
{
                    int last = row.Count - 1;
                    double.TryParse(row[last], out value);
                    if (value > 0)
                        row.RemoveAt(last);
                    text = String.Join(" ", row);
}`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and time it is working fine now